# Equivalent for inject() in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

In Ruby, I'm used to using Enumerable#inject for going through a list or other structure and coming back with some conclusion about it. For example,

```
[1,3,5,7].inject(true) {|allOdd, n| allOdd && n % 2 == 1}
```

to determine if every element in the array is odd. What would be the appropriate way to accomplish the same thing in Python?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To determine if every element is odd, I'd use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all)

```
def is_odd(x): 
    return x%2==1

result = all(is_odd(x) for x in [1,3,5,7])
```

In general, however, Ruby's `inject` is most like Python's [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
result = reduce(lambda x,y: x and y%2==1, [1,3,5,7], True)
```

`all()` is preferred in this case because it will be able to escape the loop once it finds a `False`-like value, whereas the `reduce` solution would have to process the entire list to return an answer.

Comment: Note that the built-in `reduce()` in Python 2 has been moved to [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like `reduce` in Python or `fold(r|l)'?'` from Haskell.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x and y % == 1, [1, 3, 5])
```

Comment: I've always wondered why catamorphisms are known as "fold"s in **every** functional language but Ruby and Python invent their own names...

Comment: JavaScript (1.8) uses reduce and I think Clojure uses reduce as well, but I may be mistaken on the latter one... I don't know why this is though.

Comment: This is tradition from Common Lisp, which borrowed the name from APL. I think Ruby and Python have much more Lisp influence than from any functional language.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about Lisp; I'm far too accustomed to working with the strictly-typed family of functional languages...

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably want to use `all`, which is less general than `inject`. `reduce` is the Python equivalent of `inject`, though.

```
all(n % 2 == 1 for n in [1, 3, 5, 7])
```